# How does a telephone change your voice?

Tags: digital-communications, mfcc, voice, feature-extraction

Is it due to vocal length normalization during MFCC? Please be kind enough to explain.

Comment: I would say it depends on the technology used, analog, digital, if digital, which codec, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of switched analog POTS phone lines, the audio response is shaped by the limited frequency response of the carbon microphone and the speaker in the handset.